# How do I change postition of number in 2d array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to find the biggest number in every row of a 2D array, and to put it on diametrum. I did that, but I now want to replace that number, not just declare them on diametrum. How do I change the place of numbers for my case? Here's code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int mac(int b[],int n)
{
int i,max,c=0;
max=b[0];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(max<b[i]) {max=b[i];c=i;}
}
return c;
}

int main()
{
int i,j,n;
int c;
int a[10][10],b[10];

cin>>n;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
    {
        cin>>a[i][j];
        cin.ignore();
    }
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
        b[j]=a[i][j];
    c=mac(b,n);
    /*Place where i should change something*/
    a[i][i]=a[i][c];    

}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
    {
        cout<<a[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to save the largest value in every row in your matrix to another array? Please be more specific about what you want and the error you are having.

Comment: I edited my post look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `swap`. So you have to define one temporary variable to save actual value from [i][i]. Then overwrite position [i][i] with max value and at the end you need place temp value back to position where you found max value.

```
/*Place where i should change something*/
int temp = a[i][i];
a[i][i] = a[i][c];
a[i][c] = temp;
```

Comment: Oooo, so it's like when sort array

Comment: `swap` is also used in sorting. It is basic technique how to exchange two variables.

Comment: If you are using C++11, you can also call `std::swap`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when n = 3, and input is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 the output should be 321 465 789

The code should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector< vector<int> > a;
    size_t n;
    cout<<"Enter number of value for N: ";
    cin>>n;

    a.reserve(n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i<n;i++) {
        a[i].reserve(n);
        for (size_t j =0 ; j<n;j++) {
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i<n;i++) {
        size_t index = 0;
        int max = INT_MIN;
        for (size_t j =0 ; j<n;j++) {
            if (a[i][j] >= max) {
                max = a[i][j];
                index = j;
            }
        }
        a[i][index] = a[i][i];
        a[i][i] = max;
    }

    cout<<"\nOutput\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i<n;i++) {
        for (size_t j =0 ; j<n;j++) {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i could not copile it. I get this error   warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Comment: Try now and share the compiler and flags you are using

Comment: g++ -Wall -std=c++0x -o